# Should I always set char[] last value to '\0'?

Tags: c, scanf

Should I always set the last value of a char array to `'\0'`?

```
char search_for[80];
search text here
printf("Search for: ");
scanf("%79s", search_for);
search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0';
```

This is a example from a C book.

Comment: If the `scanf` call didn't add the terminator, the call to `strlen` would not work.

Comment: Note: If `search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0';` was indeed in some C book, it means that the book is not trustworthy learning material. This is too basic mistake to be acceptable in a serious book.

Comment: The short answer is "only if you intend to use the contents of the array as a C-string". All functions that expect a string in C require the contents to the *nul-terminated*. If you are not using the contents as a string (meaning you won't try to print it using the `"%s"` format specifier, or won't pass the array to a string function such as `strcpy`, etc.., then there is no requirement. But if you want to use the contents as a *string*, then yes, it's a must.

Answer (score 2):

When using `scanf` with the `%s` format it adds it for you, one huge logical error you have though is using `strlen` when you're not sure that your string is null terminated.